# Ruby on Rails / Paperclip Gem: Does not resize images, seems to only save 'original' image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, rubygems

I have the paperclip gem installed. It's being used elsewhere so I know it's working.

I have my model,

```
class Slide < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :image, :style => {
  :large => "1400x786!",
  :medium => "128x128>",
  :small => "105x90!"
}
end
```

I created my columns

```
class AddImageToSlides < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :slides, :image_file_name,       :string
    add_column :slides, :image_content_type,    :string
    add_column :slides, :image_file_size,       :interger
    add_column :slides, :image_updated_at,      :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :slides, :image_file_name
    remove_column :slides, :image_content_type
    remove_column :slides, :image_file_size
    remove_column :slides, :image_updated_at
  end
end
```

did my raking,

```
rake db:migrate
```

I have "{ :multipart => true }" in my form

```
<%= form_for(@slide, :class=>"slidesForm", :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

And I'm trying to pull out the image info like so,

```
<div class="slidesPreview" style="background:url('<%= @slide.image.url(:large) %>') top left no-repeat;">
```

It will only work when I use "@slide.image.url", but that only shows the original photo.

I looked into public/system/images/ and it seems to only be saving original/ but not large/, medium/ or small/. I've check the error logs and nothing.

I'm hours new into learning RoR so forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `:style**s** => { ... }`, not `:style => ...` (the additional s!)

Answer (score 0):

you simply forgot to specify the size of the `photo @slide.image.url(:small), @slide.image.url(:medium), @slide.image.url(:large)`

Comment: Please read the question in full. OP did use the .url(:size) notation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following way. Its working fine.
I hope it will help to some one.

**1.add following gem in Gemfile:**

```
gem "ImageResize", "~> 0.0.5"
```

**2.run bundle**

**3.use this in controller function:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ImageResize'

#input_image_filename, output_image_filename, max_width, max_height
Image.resize('big.jpg', 'small.jpg', 40, 40)
```